# VS code python debugger Ignoring breakpoints

Tags: python-3.6, vscode-debugger

I've set a breakpoint at my vscode python ide. The debugger is just ignoring it, and  keeps running without stopping at the breakpoint.

[you can see that he just ignore the breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohyNu.png)

This is the configuration of the JSON file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry":true,         
            "logToFile": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I've downloaded the python extension and did everything as shown in the extension guide. I've also searched the web and tried to find a way to fix it but couldn't find a solution so far.

Comment: update: we opened a teamviewer session and indeed the problem occurred. After some time trying to figure out why, I tried opening folder instead of just working on the file, and in a very annoying way it worked and we solved the problem